# Define log uniform learning_rate parameter in RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

I'm doing hyperparameter tuning and I'm using `scikit-optimize` for Bayesian optimization and `RandomizedSearchCV` for a randomized search.

In sci-kit optimize I can define the `learning_rate` easily it like this:

```
space= [Real(10**-5, 10**0, "log-uniform", name='learning_rate'),
        Integer(1, 20, name='max_depth'),
        ...
       ]
```

How would I do it with `RandomizedSearchCV` (sklearn) so that the same "list" of values is used for the optimization?

```
params_randomSearch = {
              "learning_rate" : TODO,
              "min_samples_leaf": np.arange(1,30,1),
              ..
              }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation in RandomizedSearchCV()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html):

> param_distributions : dict
>
> ```
> Dictionary with parameters names (string) as keys and distributions or 
> lists of parameters to try. Distributions must
> provide a rvs method for sampling (such as those from
> scipy.stats.distributions). If a list is given, it is sampled
> uniformly.
> ```

Now, `Real` and `Integer` in scikit-optimize already implement the `rvs()` method, so you can use them directly. Just assign them in the dictionary to be used in RandomizedSearchCV.

```
params_randomSearch = {
      "learning_rate" : Real(10**-5, 10**0, "log-uniform", name='learning_rate'),
      "min_samples_leaf": np.arange(1,30,1),
              ..
              }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! A small, bit related question: do you know if its possible to limit the number of decimals?